# Implementing Replication on existing database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I'm a developer but I need to implement replication on an existing database. I'm a bit familiar with replication and I already was able to implement it but I had a few issues and the two most notable ones are:

1. Replication job affects maintenance plan -- it seems like the maintenance plan jobs can't be run because another job is currently running. I know some replication jobs are ran periodically. Can I avoid certain time of the day so it won't interfere with the maintenance plan?
2. The Distribution database grew too large and caused a no free space issue. Since this is transactional replication, publisher is continuously sending copies of the commands to the subscriber. How can I minimize the size of distribution database?

Replication has been stopped and the disk space issue is now fixed but this might happen again in the future. Before I attempt to set it up again, what should I take note of to set up the replication successfully next time?

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of tasks are the maintenance plans executing. The only replication job I can imagine interfering with another t-sql task is the snapshot job. How big is the db (tables and total size)?  How many publications are you using? I typically create several publications.

Comment: I only created 1 publication. There's a recurring job for the distribution I think. I deleted the publications and the job already because it keeps running therefore making the distribution database grow unnecessarily.

Comment: how many tables and how big is the db? I think this is still important. What if you create publication with 1 article? Do you have the same issues? What is the status of the publication, subscription and distribution in Replication Monitor. I have never had the distribution database fill up, but believe it will if the subscription is not receiving the transactions.